# Thymeleaf - Include Content From A Fragment For A Subdomain

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a file called **templates/base_blank.html**. It contains CSS, JS and logo information. I include the contents of this file on other pages with th: replace and th: insert. My problem is that: It works in files on "**/**" link but does not work on subdomains. For example it seems as **/account/img/favicon.ico** when I include the base_blank file for the **/account/forgot_password** link and it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head th:fragment="base_blank">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">

<link rel="shortcut icon"  th:href="@{img/favicon.ico}" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/bootstrap.min.css" th:href="@{css/bootstrap.min.css}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/font-awesome.min.css" th:href="@{css/font-awesome.min.css}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/AdminLTE.min.css" th:href="@{css/AdminLTE.min.css}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/skin-blue.min.css" th:href="@{css/skin-blue.min.css}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/custom.css" th:href="@{css/custom.css}" />


<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
```

Here is a little of forgot_password.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html"
  xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3"
  xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout" xmlns:form="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head th:replace="base_blank :: head"></head>
<th:block th:insert="base_blank :: body"></th:block>
```

Please pay attention to the line that includes `th:href = "@{img/favicon.ico}"`. It works on /home but does not work on /account/forgot_password.

What is the reason of this?

***Here are the some screenshots:***

[image: does not works on /account/forgot_password page]

[image: works default page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a slash at the start of the URL like this: `@{/img/favicon.ico}`. Otherwise it won't work as the URL is perceived as a relative URL and doesn't point to the correct path to the favicon (`/img/favicon.ico`) but to `/account/img/favicon.ico`.

Side note: in this case you don't need the template syntax. You can simply write `href="/img/favicon.ico"`. The `th:…` and `@{…}` are only necessary if you have anything (non-static) to be processed, e.g. a parameterized URL that depends on variables: `th:href="@{/url/with/{param}(param=${variable})}"`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been working for hours. It works for me :)

Comment: You're welcome. Please also take note of the side note I've added to my answer.